# Facebook and Wordpress Experts? please help! trying to get Facebook ID (after WP-FB AutoConn login)

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I'm trying to create a page in Wordpress that will display the user's Facebook ID after they have logged in to our Wordpress site using WP-FB AutoConn plugin (to sign in using their Facebook credentials).

For the Facebook game the site is being built to offer community support for, the user needs to know their facebook ID (which they frequently don't know how to find, which then has to be explained to them).

Since they are logging into the Wordpress site with their Facebook credentials, it seems like we should be able to have a page they can go to that would display their Facebook ID.

I used:

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();
      echo 'Username (user_login): ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User email (user_email): ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
      echo 'User first name (user_firstname): ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
      echo 'User last name (user_lastname): ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
      echo 'User display name (display_name): ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
      echo 'User ID (ID): ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
?>
```

...which displays the Wordpress login info. 
Initially I thought the user_email was their facebook ID preceded by FB_ (as in: FB_665611340@unknown.com --which is how it shows up under "Users" in Wordpress), but that must be a randomly generated number because it isn't their facebook ID.

I'm not really a coder, but trying to learn, any insight appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had WAS correct (WP-FB AutoConn uses the facevook ID in the email account it stores in Wordpress). 
I spent a week researching, testing, taking code snippets that didn't apply and trying to make them work (BEFORE I came here and asked), so, I was disappointed to see that the question itself got a negative mark.
But now I have the answer.

FOR PEOPLE WANTING TO LEARN, HERE'S THE SOLUTION:

The variable "$email4" can be whatever you like. 
Also, I decided to take the result of stripping away the extraneous stuff (from the email address) and putting the result in a variable called "$emailStripped" so I could concatenate it cleanly just using the variable name.

```
<?php $email4 = $current_user->user_email;
$emailStripped = substr($email4, strpos($email4,"<")+3, strrpos($email4, "@")-strpos($email4,"<")-3);
echo 'If you logged in using your Facebook account, your Facebook ID should be:' . "\n" . $emailStripped . "\n";
?>
```

To use this in Wordpress you will need either a plugin that allows PHP, or to create a template file with the PHP in it, create your page then select that template for it.